# How to determine continuity at origin for given 2 variable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Consider the function,

$f(x,y)=\dfrac{x^3\cos\left(\frac1y\right)+y^3\cos\left(\frac1x\right)}{ x^2+y^2},\qquad\forall x,y\neq0$

And $f(x,y)= 0,\qquad\text{ if } xy=0$

Clearly this function is not continuous at either $x-$ or $y-$ axis

As, when approaching $x-$axis,

$f(x,y)=\dfrac{x^3\cos\left(\frac1y\right)}{ x^2} = x\cos\left(\dfrac1y\right) \neq 0$

But how do you tell at origin. Approaching O via path $y=mx$ does not prove that it is discontinuous.

Comment: Prove $|\frac{x^3\cos(\frac1y)}{x^2+y^2}| \le|x|$. Then use this to show that the function is indeed continuous at $(0,0)$

Comment: How can you know so quickly that it is indeed continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By inequalities and polar coordinates we have that

$$0\le \left|\frac{x^3\cos(1/y)+y^3\cos(1/x)}{ x^2+y^2}\right|\le \left|\frac{x^3\cos(1/y)}{ x^2+y^2}\right|+\left|\frac{y^3\cos(1/x)}{ x^2+y^2}\right|\le$$$$\le \left|\frac{x^3}{ x^2+y^2}\right|+\left|\frac{y^3}{ x^2+y^2}\right|=r\left(|\cos^3\theta|+|\sin^3\theta|\right)\to 0$$

For the limit when approching the $x$ axis at a point $x=a\neq 0$ we have that

$$\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{a^3\cos(1/y)+y^3\cos(1/a)}{ a^2+y^2}=\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{a^3\cos(1/y)}{ a^2+y^2}+\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{y^3\cos(1/a)}{ a^2+y^2}$$

and the second limit is equal to $0$ but the first one doesn't exist indeed for

- $y_n=\frac1{2\pi n}\to 0 \implies \frac{a^3\cos(2\pi n)}{ a^2+\frac1{4\pi^2 n^2}}\to a$
- $y_n=\frac1{(2n-1)\pi}\to 0 \implies \frac{a^3\cos((2n-1)\pi)}{ a^2+\frac1{(2n-1)^2\pi^2}}\to -a$

Comment: Same idea as me, but polar coordinates are not necessary, see my comment above.

Comment: I did figure out some thing like this, but isn't it odd that function is not continuous at axes but is continuous at origin?

Comment: @Ingix I didn't claim it is necessary but I osten use that since it seems more clear to me. Also your method is fine. Thanks

Comment: @tatha Continuity is defined at a point, therefore it is not odd that we have continuity at the origin but not at the axes.

Comment: @tatha: When you approach a point $\neq (0,0)$  in the x-axis, your function essentially becomes $\frac{x^3\cos(\frac1y)}{x^2} = x\cos(\frac1y)$, which is *not* the same as $x$, as you incorrectly wrote. This function will oscillate more and more between $-|x|$ and $|x|$, as $y \to 0$, because then $\frac1y \to \infty$ and hence the $\cos$ will oscillate. It just happens that when we have $x=0$, this osciallation is contained in ever smaller intervals, so tends to 0 anyway. If $|x| > 0$, then the interval where it oscillates will always be $ > 0$ and hence no limit exists.

Comment: @Ingix Yes I was going to add something on that!

Comment: @Ingix Yes - good picture thanks! Also as there are no fixed values of $cos(1/y)$, this is non removable discontinuity - Am I correct?

Comment: @tatha Yes of course it is an "essential" discontinuity.

Comment: @gimusi But essential discontinuity is of complex functions which have infinite $b$ in laurent series. Or is there something I am missing?

Comment: @tatha I'm referring to that definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities#Essential_discontinuity but it is not important here