# Definition of multivariable function

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

A multivariable function has been defined as given below:

$f(x,y) =\begin{cases} \dfrac{x^3\cos\frac{1}{y} + y^3\cos\frac{1}{x} }{x^2+y^2} &x,y \neq  0,\\
\\0&\text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$

I have to investigate its continuity and differentiability at point $(0,0)$.
But I am not sure about the definition of the given function.
Does the above definition mean that $f(x,0)=0,x\neq 0$ and $f(0,y)=0,y\neq 0$?

This is important because when I consider this definition for $f(x,0)$ and $f(0,y)$ then both partial derivatives exist and are equal to $0$. Otherwise if we define $f(x,y)=0$ only for $(x,y)=(0,0)$ then partial derivatives do not exist and I can readily conclude the non-differentiability of $f(x,y)$ at $(0,0)$ as existence of partial derivatives is necessary for the function to be differentiable.

Please help me as to how to interpret this definition. Also is the function differentiable if I interpret this definition in above mentioned manner i.e. $f(x,0)=0,x\neq 0$ and
$f(0,y)=0,y\neq 0$.
Here is my work on differentiability part:
$∆z=a∆x+b∆y+k_1∆x+k_2∆y$ where $a$ and $b$ are the partial derivatives w.r.t. $x$ and $y$ respectively.
For differentiability, $k_1$ and $k_2$ should tend to $0$ as $∆x$ and $∆y$ tend to $0$.
$∆z=
\dfrac{(∆x)^3\cos\frac{1}{∆y} + (∆y)^3\cos\frac{1}{∆x} }{(∆x)^2+(∆y)^2} $.
Thus
$k_1=\dfrac{(∆x)^2\cos\frac{1}{∆y}} {(∆x)^2+(∆y)^2} $

and

$k_2=\dfrac{(∆y)^2\cos\frac{1}{∆x}} {(∆x)^2+(∆y)^2} $.

Now do $k_1$ and $k_2$ tend to $0$ as $∆x$ and $∆y$ go to $0$? If I take $∆x=∆y$ then $k_1$ comes out to be limit of $\frac {1}{2}cos\frac{1}{∆y}$ as $∆y$ goes to $0$ which does not exist.
Am I doing it correctly? Please suggest.

Comment: It means that $f(x,y) = \frac{x^3 \cos(1/y) + y^3 \cos(1/x)}{x^2 + y^2}$ if *both* $x$ and $y$ are nonzero, and $f(x,y) = 0$ otherwise. So, if either $x$ or $y$ is $0$, then $f(x,y) = 0$. Notice that the given formula does not make sense if either $x$ or $y$ is $0$, because we can't divide by $0$.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy If I define it otherwise as mentioned, is the function differentiable at $(0,0)$?

Comment: @HARVEERRAWAT Your check in the editing is for continuity at $(0,0)$ and not for differentiability. Indeed the function is continuous at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 3):

Usually the notation $x,y\neq0$ stands for $x\neq 0 \land y\neq 0$. Note also that the expression for this case would be not defined when $xy=0$ that is $x\neq 0 \lor y\neq 0$
. Therefore the definition means that $f(x,y)=0$ when $x= 0 \lor y=0$, that is $f(0,0)=f(x,0)=f(0,y)=0$.

---

For differentiability at $(0,0)$ we can consider

$$\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)} \frac{\dfrac{h^3\cos\frac{1}{k} + k^3\cos\frac{1}{h} }{h^2+k^2}-f(0,0)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)} \dfrac{h^3\cos\frac{1}{k} + k^3\cos\frac{1}{h} }{(h^2+k^2)^\frac 3 2}$$

which doesn't exist (e.g. by polar coordinates), therefore the function is continuous but not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Refer also to the related

- [Existence of Partial Derivatives Implies Differentiability](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2646296/505767)
- [How to determine continuity at origin for given 2 variable function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2897453/505767)

Comment: What about the differentiability at origin?

Comment: I’ve just mentioned that $f(0,0)=0$.

Comment: Let add your work on that if you have doubts to study differentiability. I’ll take a look to it. Bye